# Can I access Zimbra's Global Address List (GAL) over CardDAV?

Tags: email, email-client, webdav, zimbra

We've got roughly 40k users on an outsourced Zimbra install. Most users are fine with the webmail versions, but some want to integrate other desktop MUAs. Their specific complaint is using the GAL to lookup emails from names and such. For random reasons, we don't have a good whitepages LDAP, and the Zimbra LDAP is not accessible. This could be changed, but I suspect it will take a good deal of convincing and coordination. Possibly lawyers.

In the meantime, **is it possible to access the Zimbra GAL via a cardDAV interface?** I've got Evolution working with my personal CardDAV contacts list, but that's a far smaller set than the entire 40k users.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/es-ES/thunderbird/) + [Zindus](http://www.zindus.com/). It allow you to synchronize your address book and also read the GAL

Comment: And how does it read the GAL? LDAP, or DAV?

Comment: It uses DAV for reading the GAL

Comment: So I went digging through the source code and it looks like it uses SOAP. Am I wrong here?

Comment: And LDAP. No DAV urls that I can find

Comment: I know it does not access the LDAP directly because my ldap is not exposed. Anyway, what differences does it make if it uses DAV or SOAP?

Comment: Can't get apple mail to use soap, now can I?

Comment: I can't tell about apple, my answer is about Thunderbird. Just change Evolution for Thunderbird and install the plugin. I think apple uses ActiveSync for PIM sync. You cannot get that from Zimbra Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You could access to the GAL with this url using DAV.

`https://zimbraDomain.com/dav/galsync/_InternalGAL/`

You should insert the username and password and then, you'll get all the global list.